# Not fetching SDL embedded semantic schema from DD4T class

Tags: 2013, dd4t, dxa

I have created Schema with two XML names (fields)

1. Text field
2. link of type Embedded schema.

When I try to fetch the SchematicSchema from Entity/Model class, I see only text field, but not the embeded links data. Can some one help here.

**Schema**:

```xml
<xsd:annotation>
  <xsd:appinfo>
    <tcm:Labels xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">
      <tcm:Label ElementName="headline" Metadata="false">Heading</tcm:Label>
      <tcm:Label ElementName="link" Metadata="false">Links</tcm:Label>
      <tcm:Label ElementName="linkText" Context="tcm:4">Link Text</tcm:Label
      <tcm:Label ElementName="externalLink" Context="tcm:4">External Link</tcm:Label>
      <tcm:Label ElementName="internalLink" Context="tcm:4">-- OR -- Internal Link</tcm:Label>
      <tcm:Label ElementName="alternateText" Context="tcm:4-89-8">Alternate Text</tcm:Label>
    </tcm:Labels>
  </xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation>
<xsd:element name="CustomerInfo">
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="headline" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:normalizedString">
        <xsd:annotation>
          <xsd:appinfo>
            <ExtensionXml xmlns="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0"></ExtensionXml>
          </xsd:appinfo>
        </xsd:annotation>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="link" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="EmbeddedLink">
        <xsd:annotation>
          <xsd:appinfo>
            <ExtensionXml xmlns="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">
              <configuration xmlns="http://www.sdltridion.com/2011/SiteEdit">
                <field>
                  <editable>true</editable>
                </field>
              </configuration>
            </ExtensionXml>
            <tcm:EmbeddedSchema xlink:href="tcm:4" xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:title="Link"></tcm:EmbeddedSchema>
          </xsd:appinfo>
        </xsd:annotation>
```

**Model:**

```cs
public class xxxx extends AbstractEntity {
    private String headline;

    private List<Link> links;

    public String getHeadline() {
        return headline;
    }

    public void setHeadline(String headline) {
        this.headline = headline;
    }

    public List<Link> getLinks() {
        return links;
    }

    public void setLinks(List<Link> links) {
        this.links = links;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "xxx{" +
                "headline='" + headline + '\'' +
                ", links=" + links +
                '}';
    }
}
```

---

```
final SemanticSchema semanticSchema = localization.getSemanticSchemas() .get(Long.parseLong(component.getSchema().getId().split("-")[1]));
```

Comment: after you modified your schema, did you republish your site settings page and did you 'refresh' your website's config settings by going to the url [website]/admin/refresh ?